# Obtaining and retrieving Access Tokens with OpenID/Microsoft Identity Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api

Getting the below error in my `Startup.cs` file due to the inclusion of `.AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("GraphApi"))` in `Startup.cs` file.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'MicrosoftIdentityAppCallsWebApiAuthenticationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddMicrosoftGraph' and no accessible extension method 'AddMicrosoftGraph' accepting a first argument of type 'MicrosoftIdentityAppCallsWebApiAuthenticationBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I have both `Microsoft.Graph` and `Microsoft.Graph.Core` Nuget packages added to my project.

Also have the below using statements at the top of my `Startup.cs` file, although they are not being used apparently.

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Core;
```

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpClient();
    var scopes = new[] { "Files.ReadWrite.All " };
 
    services
        .AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
        // Add the possibility of acquiring a token to call a protected web API
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(scopes)
        // Enables controllers and pages to get GraphServiceClient by dependency injection
        // And use an in memory token cache
        .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("GraphApi"))
        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
}
```

I'm not sure what is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refence namespace `Microsoft.Identity.Web`

Simply add with `using`

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Core;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpClient();
    var scopes = new[] { "Files.ReadWrite.All " };
    services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    // Add the possibility of acquiring a token to call a protected web API
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(scopes)
    // Enables controllers and pages to get GraphServiceClient by dependency injection
    // And use an in memory token cache
        .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("GraphApi"))
        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
}
```

Resources:

[MicrosoftGraphExtensions](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph/MicrosoftGraphExtensions.cs)

Comment: I've already got this one added.